# Kotlin multiplatform: Skipping publish of some platforms using Gradle Kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I have Kotlin multiplatform project. And I would like to publish part artifacts to repository, skipping another part.
I am using following config:

```
kotlin {
    jvm()
    val iosArm64 = iosArm64()
    val iosX64 = iosX64()

    configure(listOf(iosArm64, iosX64)) {
        binaries {
            framework("some") {
                embedBitcode("disable")
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            ...
        }
    }

    publications {
        register("mavenJava", MavenPublication::class) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to skip iosX64 for example, as I do a "Fat framework" and I wan to publish it. How to configure Gradle Kotlin dsl to avoid publication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achived using task configuration of maven-publish:

```
tasks.withType<PublishToMavenRepository>().configureEach {
    onlyIf {
        (publication.artifactId == "my-artifact-1") || (publication.artifactId == "my-artifact-2")
    }
}
```